# Same separation between elements of different sizes

Tags: css

I am using `justify-content: space-around;` in the upper element as in the sub-elements, but the sub-elements can have different sizes according to the user's input. I had thought of simply putting that each element (date name and the option to delete) would occupy a certain space with % but I have already become curious in case there is some way to do it using flex.
[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaqQJ.jpg)

[As I would like it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjOmU.jpg)

Comment: Show your CSS code and perhaps a picture of what you want it to look like. I'm not sure I follow what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Phaelaxz I have updated with a photo, I hope to explain well

Comment: Try `justify-content: space-between;`

Comment: Css-grid is your friend here or use a table since that seems to be what you have here

Answer (score 1):

In such situations, you should use `display:grid` which is built for such usages. So here is a simple code:

```css
listitem span{
  display:block;
}
.list-item{
  width:300px;
  padding:5px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
  border:1px solid blue;
  border-radius:3px;
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:auto 1fr auto;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}

.event{
  justify-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-item">
  <span>2020-10-10</span>
  <span class="event">Dinner</span>
  <img class="delete-icon" src="https://img.icons8.com/android/24/000000/trash.png"/>
</div>
<div class="list-item">
    <span>2020-10-10</span>
    <span class="event">Go visit mum</span>
    <img class="delete-icon" src="https://img.icons8.com/android/24/000000/trash.png"/>
  
</div>
<div class="list-item">
  <span>2020-10-10</span>
  <span class="event">Buying eggs and bread</span>
  <img class="delete-icon" src="https://img.icons8.com/android/24/000000/trash.png"/>
  
</div>
```

Run the snippet to see the result. 
But if you want to do it with flexbox anyway, you just have to set `justify-content` to `space-between`.